# Cannot initialize a by-reference variable with a value C#

Tags: c#, fiddlercore

Having this error **Cannot initialize a by-reference variable with a value** I'm fairly new to C# just trying trying to fix up a abandoned open source project.

Here's the code:

```
private bool CertificateHandler(bool valueExist)
    {
      if (!CertMaker.rootCertExists() && !CertMaker.createRootCert() || (CertMaker.rootCertIsTrusted() ? 1 : (CertMaker.trustRootCert() ? 1 : 0)) == 0)
        return false;
      // ISSUE: explicit reference operation
      ref string local1 = @this.fiddlerCertInfos._fiddlerCert;
      if (local1 == null)
        local1 = FiddlerApplication.Prefs.GetStringPref("fiddler.certmaker.bc.cert", (string) null);
      // ISSUE: explicit reference operation
      ref string local2 = @this._fiddlerCertInfos._privateKey;
      if (local2 == null)
        local2 = FiddlerApplication.Prefs.GetStringPref("fiddler.certmaker.bc.key", (string) null);
      if (!valueExist)
        this.appRegistry.UpdateRegistry(new List<RegistryInfo>()
        {
          new RegistryInfo()
          {
            Name = "FiddlerCert",
            Value = (object) this._fiddlerCertInfos._fiddlerCert,
            RegistryValueKind = RegistryValueKind.String
          },
          new RegistryInfo()
          {
            Name = "PrivateKey",
            Value = (object) this._fiddlerCertInfos._privateKey,
            RegistryValueKind = RegistryValueKind.String
          }
        });
      return true;
    }
```

Error line:

```
ref string local1 = @this.fiddlerCertInfos._fiddlerCert;
ref string local2 = @this._fiddlerCertInfos._privateKey;
```

Comment: See [ref - Ref locals (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref#ref-locals) and [Working With Ref Returns And Ref Local (C# Corner)7.0](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-ref-returns-and-ref-local-in-c-sharp-7-0/) and [ref returns and ref locals (AdamSitnik)](https://adamsitnik.com/ref-returns-and-ref-locals/)

Comment: `ref string` types is a very advanced C# concept, which is very rarely used. Try to rewrite the code with just "string" (you'll probably have to change the members of `fiddlerCertInfos` to properties)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref#ref-locals

You can't assign a local reference variable with a non reference value. So either you need to remove the ref-keyword for the local variable or add 'ref' in front of the value which is assigned.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your knowledge & experience. But your answer has a low quality. Sometimes a comment or a flag/close may be more relevant. To help you improve your answersplease read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), [How do I write a good answer to a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) & [Answering technical questions helpfully](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully).

Comment: Can you better expand and explain, please?